Proving Simplicity of Zeros of a Polynomial.
Let $\epsilon>0$ and let $P(z)=a_nz^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1z+a_0$ be a polynomial with complex coefficients such that $|a_k-1|<\epsilon$ for all $k=0,1,\cdots,n$. Show that for $\epsilon$ sufficiently small, $P(z)$ has $n$ simple zeros in the annulus $\{z \in \mathbb{C}:1/2<|z|<2\}$.
Showing the existence of such zeros using Rouche's theorem isn't too hard (I won't prove it here, but just choose the obvious candidates for the contours $|z|=2$ and $|z|=1/2$ and apply Rouche, the result follows without much struggle). Proving simplicity has me stumped.
The immediate intuition is the reapply Rouche to $P'(z)$ and hope that the zeros of $P'(z)$ are either all outside of $D(0,2)$, or all contained within $D(0,1/2)$. Neither of these turn out very much. In fact, the zeros of $P'(z)$ should in fact also be within $D(0,2)$, and there's no obvious way to prove its roots are in $D(0,1/2)$. Indeed, the hope would be to show
$$a_1+2a_2/2+3a_3/2^2+\cdots+(n-1)a_{n-1}/2^{n-2}<na_n/2^{n-1}$$
but this is only going to hold for small $n$.
The only other tool I can think of is to use the argument principal, but without knowing the order of the zeros before hand, I don't see another way to evaluate the integral
$$\int_{\partial D(0,2)} \frac{P'(z)}{P(z)}\ dz$$
Are there other tools I'm failing to think of that can prove the simplicity of a zero?

Take $f$ to be the polynomial
$$f(z)=1+z+z^2+\cdots+z^n.$$
Its roots are the $n$-th roots of unity different from $1$. For each of those roots, take a small disk $D_k$ around it, such that

the disks $D_k$ are disjoint.
they are all contained in the annulus $1/2<|z|<2$.

$f$ takes a non-zero minimum on the boundaries of each disk, call it $\eta_k$. Call $\eta$ the minimum of the $\eta_k$. If $z\in\partial D_k$, for any $k$, we have
$$|P(z)-f(z)|\leq|a_n-1|2^n+\cdots+|a_0-1|2^0<\varepsilon(2^{n+1}-1)$$
and upon taking $\varepsilon$ small enough, this is less than $\eta$. Rouché then implies that $f$ and $P$ have the same number of zeroes in each $D_k$.
Since $f$ has exactly one simple root in each $D_k$ because we picked them disjoint, so does $P$, and this concludes the proof.
